Regex to prevent certain ranges
I have currently the following regex
ZL[^0-9].{16}_.{3}PAD_N.{26}\.PIC

which matches filenames like
ZLF_1177_0771428479_534PAD_N0530130SALP09217_1100LMV01.PIC

but would like to change the regex so that the 9 characters at the position SALP09217
can not take the ranges
SALP00000-00899, SALP01000-03099 and SALP05000-06999

(note that SALT00000-00899, or any other substring other than SALP are allowed only those that start with SALP are to be excluded)
The following regex works partially
ZL[^0-9].{16}_.{3}PAD_N.{7}(?!(SALP00[0-8][0-9][0-9])|(SALP0[1-3]0[0-9][0-9])|(SALP0[5-6][0-9][0-9][0-9])).*\.PIC

but will allow strings larger than the original regex would allow. For example it allows
ZLF_1177_0771428479_534PAD_N0530130SALP09217_1100LMV01.PIC

which is correct but also
ZLF_1177_0771428479_534PAD_N0530130SALP09217_1100LMV01LARGER.PIC

which is not
The "ideal" regex would be
ZL[^0-9].{16}_.{3}PAD_N.{7}(?!(SALP00[0-8][0-9][0-9])|(SALP0[1-3]0[0-9][0-9])|(SALP0[5-6][0-9][0-9][0-9])).{10}\.PIC

but
ZLF_1177_0771428479_534PAD_N0530130SALP09217_1100LMV01.PIC

will not be a match.
Any suggestions?

I would suggest just rewriting the requirment using a whitelist approach.

@TimBiegeleisen I suspect the problem is not the inversion but making a range with regexes, which they are only somewhat suitable for.

Please add a tag for the language you are using, both to identify the regex engine and to permit readers to offer non-regex solutions. Must you use a regex?

@CarySwoveland Yes I must use a regex.

"Yes I must use a regex." Just out of curiosity, why?

Regex is a terrible tool for ranges - even for 1digit ranges. But for 3 ranges to be excluded (or 4 ranges to be included) - 5 digits each - it is quite insane. Doable, but terrible. As the other friends here suggested: please find a different way, depending on the details of your task.

instead of .* you need .{19} since lookaheads consume nothing. and you need to split the 1000-3099 range into 1000-2999, 3000-3099

ZL[^0-9].{16}_.{3}PAD_N.{7}(?!SALP0(0[0-8]|[1256][0-9]|30)[0-9]{2}).{19}\.PIC

@CarySwoveland It is part of the framework I inherited where every rule (many more besides this one) is handled via regex. It would not be practical to change the architecture.

@virolino, calm down! It's not so bad here. :-)

You wrote "...the 9 characters at the position SALP09217 can not take the ranges...". I assumed you meant that the first 4 of those characters must be 'SALP' and the last 5 must be digits that do not "fall in specified ranges", but in a comment on my answer @jhnc pointed out that my assumption may not be correct. Is my assumption correct?

@CarySwoveland Sorry they can not be SALP but can be any other string. I will update the question.

You added "note that SALP00000-00899, etc are allowed" but on the line obove you wrote (previously), "...cannot take the ranges SALP00000-00899 ...". I'm confused. Are you saying that the string may contain any 9 characters where you have "SALP00000" in your examples, but if they start "SALP" the following five characters must be are digits, which if interpreted as an integer, does not fall within any of the three designative ranges?

@CarySwoveland Thanks I meant a different word like SALT. Updated.

The negative lookahead can be much simpler than Wiktor's answer.
Given exclusion ranges:
SALP00000-00899
SALP01000-03099
SALP05000-06999

it is clear that all start SALP0 and end [0-9]{2}.
Then the remaining two digits are:
0[0-8]
1[0-9] 2[0-9] 30
5[0-9] 6[0-9]

which can be regrouped:
0[0-8]
1[0-9] 2[0-9] 5[0-9] 6[0-9]
30

and combined into: 0[0-8]|[1256][0-9]|30.
So the whole negative lookahead is just:
(?!SALP0(0[0-8]|[1256][0-9]|30)[0-9]{2})

It is incorporated by splitting .{26} in two at the appropriate offset, as stated. Note that lookarounds consume no characters, so total length does not change:
ZL[^0-9].{16}_.{3}PAD_N.{7}(?!SALP0(?:0[0-8]|[1256][0-9]|30)[0-9]{2}).{19}\.PIC


You string is valid if and only if it matches the following regular expression.
(?x)             # invoke extended (aka free-spacing) mode
^                # match beginning of string
ZL\D             # match 'ZL' then a char other than a digit
.{16}_.{3}       # match 16 characters other than line terminators
                 # (COTLTs), then literal then 3 CORTLs
PAD_N            # match literal
\d{7}            # match 7 digits
(?:              # begin non-capture group
  (?!SALP)       # negative lookahead asserts that next 4 chars are not 'SALP'
  .{9}           # match 9 COTLTs
|                # or
  SALP           # match literal
  (?:            # begin a non-capture group
    009\d{2}     # match a literal then 2 digits
  |              # or
    03[1-9]\d{2} # match a literal then a char in the char case then 2 digits
  |              # or
    0[4789]\d{3} # match a literal then char in char class then 3 digits
  |              # or
    [1-9]\d{4}   # match char in char class then 4 digits
  )              # end non-capture class
)                # end non-capture class
_.{9}            # match literal then 9 COTLTs
\.PIC$           # match literal at end of string

Demo

this may well be what is actually wanted, but technically the spec provided allows non-SALP and non-digits in those 9 positions, but this regex doesn't

user2175783, I've modified my answer to conform with your clarification of the question. Please tell me if my understanding of the question is still not correct. @jhnc, you were right.

I'm not convinced this double negative is clearer or less errorprone than directly stating what is not allowed (which you are now partially doing anyway). You seem to have left out SALP03[1-9][0-9]{2}

@jhnc, thank you for pointing out my oversight. With my newfound understanding of the question I am indifferent to the two approaches that could be taken concerning the "ranges" defined by the five digits following 'SALP', but I think it is worthwhile to have both represented in the answers (and in your comment).

I just find long code confusing :-) btw, you're still missing 032, 033, 034, etc.

You can use
ZL[^0-9].{16}_.{3}PAD_N.{7}(?!SALP0(?:0(?:0{0,2}[0-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2})|(?:100[0-9]|10[1-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3}|30[0-9]{2})|(?:500[0-9]|50[1-9][0-9]|5[1-9][0-9]{2}|6[0-9]{3}))(?!\d)).{19}\.PIC

See the regex demo.
The (?!SALP0(?:0(?:0{0,2}[0-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2})|(?:100[0-9]|10[1-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3}|30[0-9]{2})|(?:500[0-9]|50[1-9][0-9]|5[1-9][0-9]{2}|6[0-9]{3}))) negative lookahead fails the match if there are SALP00000-00899, SALP01000-03099 and SALP05000-06999 ranges immediately to the right of the current location.
Note:

SALP00(?:0{0,2}[0-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}) matches SALP00000-00899,
SALP0(?:100[0-9]|10[1-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3}|30[0-9]{2}) matches SALP01000-03099 and
SALP0(?:500[0-9]|50[1-9][0-9]|5[1-9][0-9]{2}|6[0-9]{3}) matches SALP05000-06999.
(?!\d) after the alternatives in the lookahead makes sure the numbers are checked in full, not partially, so that SALP00903 and suchlike values could be matched
Also, see how I divided the .{26} pattern into .{7} and .{19} to make the lookahead work.


@CarySwoveland That was due to partial match of the alternatives in the lookahead, so it is an easy fix.
